# JSF primefaces update dialog not passing value to bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having a issue where I have the the following:

I can add roles without a problem but when I need to delete or edit its not working due to the *roleController.selectedRole* being **null**.
At first I had the managed bean as requestScope and I though that null could be coming from there as with every request the bean is recreated.
So I changed to ViewScoped fixed the add button to work again but still I'm getting the same problem with edit and delete.

What is happening is the following: I select a row and click the button edit. This shows the dialog with the role information properly. But when I click edit, I get null value.
I've seen several examples and it seems I'm not doing anything wrong. But I might be missing something really basic :/

Any insight will be most appreciated!

As for the bean I have the following:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
....
private Roles selectedRole = new Roles();
(I have the normal setter and getter)
    public void edit() {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "====> EDIT ROLE" + selectedRole.getRole());
    }
```

The page is as follows ommitting the ui:define and header things.

```
<h:form id="contentView">
    <p:dataTable id="lstRoles" var="r" value="#{roleController.rolesList}" selectionMode="single" 
                 selection="#{roleController.selectedRole}" rowKey="#{r.role}" paginator="true"
                 paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}  {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,50" rows="10">
        <p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{r.role}">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{r.role}"></p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Description">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{r.description}"></h:outputLabel>
        </p:column>                
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="New" icon="ui-icon-star" oncomplete="newRoleDialog.show()"></p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="editRoleDialog.show()" update=":editRoleForm:editRolePanel"></p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-trash"></p:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:blockUI block="lstRoles" trigger="lstRoles">
        LOADING 
    </p:blockUI>
</h:form>

<!-- Edit User -->
<p:dialog header="Edit User" widgetVar="editRoleDialog" resizable="false">
    <h:form id="editRoleForm">
        <p:panelGrid id="editRolePanel" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Role: "></h:outputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{roleController.selectedRole.role}"></h:outputText>

            <h:outputText value="Description: "></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{roleController.selectedRole.description}" required="true"></p:inputText>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Confirm" update=":contentView:lstRoles :growl" oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'editRoleDialog','editRoleForm');" actionListener="#{roleController.edit()}"></p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton type="reset" value="reset"></p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

**EDIT:** I'm using Glassfish 3.1 with primefaces 3.5

**EDIT 2:** So, it seems I cannot use a outputlabel. If I change to input then I get the required values in the managedbean (I guess it's because it calls the setter although I assume it was already taken care of when selecting the row). But I don't want to edit the 1st fields as this is the PK key and it's used also as FK in the tables. But at least know I know what's going on, or more or less.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the role selected from the datatable to the managedbean's selectedrole attribute, try this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="editRoleDialog.show()" update=":editRoleForm:editRolePanel">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{roleController.selectedRole}" value="#{r}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

You'll most likely need to make the bean ViewScoped, too.

Edit: I didn't know about the selection feature of datatable, to clarify if you are using that you don't need the above code.

Comment: thanks but that does not work either :/ if I change the bean to viewscoped all stops working, I guess I'll need to add extra <f:ajax execute="@from"> if I leave as RequestScope and that property it's always pointing to the first recorde and still the bean get's null.
I'll try to convert everything into ViewScope and see the result!!! thanks

Comment: Look closer at the code. OP is using `<p:dataTable selection>`. Opening the data in edit dialog is working fine. OP is complaining that it isn't available anymore when submitting the edit dialog.

Answer (score -1):

try **valueChangeListener** attribute in inputtext. You normaly really hard to have a part of entity in **@SessionScope**. Its sure work if u use

```
<inputText value="#{bean.value}"/>
```

but may not work if u use

```
<inputText value="#{bean.entity.value}"/>
```

. use **valueChangeListener** and create a method like this can force to save value for your entity.

```
public void saveValue(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Integer newValue = (Integer) event.getNewValue();//u can use getOldValue to get value before
        entity.setValue(newValue);
    }
```

Goodluck!